# Installing smartcard reader in Chrome

Tags: chrome, smartcard

I have a smartcard and reader installed in Debian 8.5; it works under Firefox. I am trying to activate in Chrome. I followed [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommonAccessCard#Google_Chrome.2FChromium_Setup) and got the following:

```
> cd
> modutil -dbdir sql:.pki/nssdb/ -add "CAC Module" -libfile /usr/lib/libcackey.so

WARNING: Performing this operation while the browser is running could cause
corruption of your security databases. If the browser is currently running,
you should exit browser before continuing this operation. Type 
'q <enter>' to abort, or <enter> to continue: 

ERROR: Failed to add module "CAC Module". Probable cause : "File not found".
```

and yet the file indeed exists

```
> ls -oh /usr/lib/libcackey.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser 122K Sep 30  2015 /usr/lib/libcackey.so
```

(Oddly, when I tried the same command with sudo, it failed but with a different message, `Probable cause : "Failure to load dynamic library".`)

I changed the owner of `~/.pki/nssdb/pkcs11.txt` from root to me and now I get the message: `Probable cause : "Failure to load dynamic library"` and the following is the listing

```
 >  modutil -dbdir sql:.pki/nssdb/ -list

 Listing of PKCS #11 Modules
 -----------------------------------------------------------
   1. NSS Internal PKCS #11 Module
     slots: 2 slots attached
    status: loaded

     slot: NSS Internal Cryptographic Services
    token: NSS Generic Crypto Services

     slot: NSS User Private Key and Certificate Services
    token: NSS Certificate DB

   2. CAC Module
    library name: /usr/lib/libcackey.so
     slots: 2 slots attached
    status: loaded

     slot: CACKey Slot
    token: 

     slot: CACKey Slot
    token: US Government Certificates
 -----------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I install the library?

Comment: Does `.pki/nssdb/` exist?

Comment: @depquid Yes, I should have mentioned that. It is a directory with `cert9.db`, `key4.db`, and `pkcs11.txt`. The first two are owned by me, the last one by root. Permissions are all 600.

Comment: Why is `pkcs11.txt` owned by root?  If it's under your home directory (i.e. in `~/.pki/nssdb`), then it should be owned by you.

Comment: @depquid I don't know why it has that ownership, whatever installed it installed it that way. Nevertheless, I changed ownership. It still fails, but I now get the `Probable cause : "Failure to load dynamic library"` message.

Comment: Please add the output of `modutil -dbdir sql:.pki/nssdb/ -list` to your question.

Comment: If your problem has been solved, please select the answer that was most helpful to you so that this question won't appear unanswered.  You may select your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem apparently was that the ownership of .pki/nssdb/pkcs11.txt was root rather than me. With changed ownership, there is an error message implying that the dynamic library did not load, but everything seems to function correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You were getting the first error ("File not found") because of incorrect ownership of `~/.pki/nssdb/pkcs11.txt`.  Since it couldn't be accessed, it appeared to modutil to not exist.

The second error ("Failure to load dynamic library") is because the library is already loaded.  See the second entry in the module list: "CAC Module": "library name: /usr/lib/libcackey.so".  So there's nothing else to do.

Comment: OK that is an explanation. In the case where the library is already loaded, I'd say the second message has confusing wording. Regardless, there should have been a time when the library wasn't loaded, and then the modutil command loaded it without an error message, but I never saw a non-error response to the modutil command.